# QGlWidget fullscreen no menu

Tags: qt, fullscreen, qglwidget

I have an app that is a single QGlwidget with a right-click QMenu created when needed.
The data is drawn in an overridden paintEvent()

But in fullscreen mode the menu isn't displayed.
Am I better having a QGraphicsScene as the parent window and a QGlWidget as the sole child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-7556) on Qt's bug list which seems related to your issue. The bug describes it as a possible driver issue with NVidia cards. It also looks like there is a workaround.

Comment: Thanks - yes they are all NVidia cards, will test it on monday

Comment: Updated link to the bug report: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-7556